# material ui select field does not print text after selection

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I am facing an issue I can't resolve, and quite weird indeed. I am using `material-ui: 0.18.5`, a basic `SelectField` and several `MenuItem`:

```
          <SelectField
            maxHeight={350}
            floatingLabelText={translate(messages.label)}
            value={this.props.op[OP_FIELDS.ID]}
            onChange={this.handleFieldChange(OP_FIELDS.ID)}
          >
            {this.props.op.map((item) =>
              <MenuItem
                key={`op_${item.key}`}
                value={item.key}
                primaryText={item.labelFR}
                label={item.labelFR}
              />
            )}
          </SelectField>
```

The SelectField displays properly and when I select a field, I see with the `react` addon on chrome that my props is correctly set up. Also I see the floating label correctly displayed. But the main label is not!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, the `key`of `onChange` method of the `SelectField` is not the `key` of the `MenuItem` but its index, as stated by the doc:

```
key: The index of the selected menu item
```

This is quite confusing though.